# Php code to validate and send form data to email

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

Php code to validate and send form data to an email address

My php wont validate my ajax post call method and have my formdata sent to an email address on submit button click. I am probably missing out some codes and Here is a sample of what my code looks like.

Any answers?

```
<body>

<div class="tab_content active_tab" id="name">
<form method="post" class="import_form">
<input type="hidden" id="doc_type" name="doc_type" value="" required>
<textarea name="name" placeholder="Name" required></textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="importer1" value="1">
<button type="submit">SEND</button>
</form>
</div>

<div class="tab_content" id="account_type">
<form method="post" class="import_form">
<input type="hidden" id="doc_type" name="doc_type" value="" required>
<textarea name="account_type" placeholder="ACCOUNT TYPE" required></textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="date" placeholder="Date" required>
<input type="hidden" name="importer2" value="1">
<button type="submit">SEND</button>
</form>
</div>

</div>
</div>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.html"></script>
<script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.html"></script>
</body>

<script>
var root_link = "index.html";
forms =  document.getElementsByClassName('import_form');
for(let i = 0;i < forms.length; i++){
forms[i].addEventListener('submit',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
data = new FormData(this);
request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    //alert(this.responseText);
  if(this.responseText == true){
  location = 'image.html';
  }
    }
  };
}
function open_tap(tab){
var tabs = document.getElementsByClassName('tab_content');
var tabs_key = document.getElementsByClassName('import_tab');
for(let i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++){
tabs[i].style.display = 'none';
}
for(let i = 0; i < tabs_key.length; i++){
tabs_key[i].style.borderBottom  = 'none';
}
document.getElementById(tab).style.display = 'block';
document.getElementsByClassName(tab)[0].style.borderBottom  = '1px solid #fff';
}
</script>

<script>
$("#loader").hide();    
function loading(t){
    $("#loader").show();
    setTimeout(function(){
    $("#loader").hide();    
    },t);
}
$('#name').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var a = $('#name_val').val(),
    b = $('#doc_type').val();
    $.ajax({
    method:"POST",
    url:"set.php",
    data:{name:a,doc_type:b,importer1:true},
    beforeSend:function(){
        loading(2500);
    },
    success:function(r){
        loading(5000);
    //  alert(r);
        location = 'image-2.html';
    }
    });
});

$('#accountype_form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var a = $('#accountype_val').val(),
    b = $('#doc_type').val(), c = $('#date').val();
    $.ajax({
    method:"POST",
    url:"set.php",
    data:{accounttype_val:a,doc_type:b,date:c,importer2:true},
    beforeSend:function(){
        loading(2500);
    },
    success:function(r){
        loading(5000);
        location = 'image-2.html';
    }
    });
});



</script>
```

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$to = "anything@domain.com";
$name = $_POST['name'];
$acounttype = $_POST['accounttype'];



$errorMSG = "";


if (empty($_POST["name"])) {

    $errorMSG = "location:'image2_html'";

} else {

    $name = $_POST["name"];

}



if (empty($_POST["accounttype"])) {

    $errorMSG .= "location:'image2_html'";

} else {

    $accounttype = $_POST["accounttype"];

}




?>
```

Comment: Can you add the PHP code you wrote that is not working?

Comment: Yes I have just added the PHP code

Comment: That code doesn't do much except set some variables. It's really unclear what the problem is. Try to clarify your actual question (instead of just pointlessly repeating the same text twice). Both the specific requirement and the current issue are unclear. "I am trying" doesn't tell us anything useful about what's going on. See [ask] and how to create a [mre] for more guidance.

Comment: `my ajax post call method`...which one? You've got two, which both go to set.php. Are they both a problem? Is the PHP code you've shown the code from set.php? Because that code doesn't _do_ anything - it just sets some variables and then stops. It's completely pointless currently. If you want it to indicate something back to the client-side about the result of the validation, then it needs to echo a response.

Comment: It's also missing a closing Brace, so in the even it does get called I imagine it creates a 500 server error